# AngularJS - factory not being called when URL changes

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm new to Angular JS and struggling to get a factory to return data when my URL has changed.

In my app config I have:

```
.state('app.sessionActivity', {
            url: "/session/:sessionid/activity/:id",
            views: {
                'menuContent' :{
                    templateUrl: "templates/activity.html",
                    controller: 'SessionActivityCtrl'
                }
            }
        })
```

My Controller:

```
.controller('SessionActivityCtrl', ['$scope', '$stateParams', 'localJSONData', function($scope, $stateParams, localJSONData) {

var activityID = $stateParams.id;
var activityVideoURLSRC = null;

localJSONData.getJSONData()
    .success(function(data){
        $scope.activityData = data[activityID - 1];   
    });

}])
```

My factory:

```
.factory('localJSONData', ['$http', '$stateParams', function($http, $stateParams){
var sessionID = $stateParams.sessionid;

return {
    getJSONData: function(){
        if(sessionID == 1){
            return $http.get('json/session1_activities.json', {cache:false});
        }
        if(sessionID == 2){
            return $http.get('json/session2_activities.json', {cache:false});
        }
}
}
}])
```

This all works when I first load the page and go to the URL (for example) /session/1/activity/1 for the first time. But then when I load the URL (for example) /session/2/activity/2 the data is from session 1. When I debug in chrome, the factory doesn't get called the second time.

Am I not getting something conceptually, not using the correct methods, or are there any errors in my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you're passing in `sessionID` isn't really a good idea, why don't you pass it to the method in your factory itself?

```
return {
    getJSONData: function(sessionID){
        if(sessionID == 1){
            return $http.get('json/session1_activities.json', {cache:false});
        }
        if(sessionID == 2){
            return $http.get('json/session2_activities.json', {cache:false});
        }
}
```

Controller:

```
localJSONData.getJSONData($stateParams.id)
    .success(function(data){
        $scope.activityData = data[activityID - 1];   
    });
```

The reason this works the first time your app loads is because `$stateParams` correctly evaluates the initial state's parameter, but doesn't update after that. The best way to do it would be what I posted above.